# Weblogic: how can I see what servlet and filters the request is processed by?

Tags: servlets, weblogic, servlet-filters

Good day!

I have a weblogic server and an enterprise application with lots of servlets and filters. I add my servlet (in fact, it is jersey-servlet) but requests that I send to my servlet are caught by something else and I have a 404 error.

So, is there a way (may be using weblogic console) how to see which filter are applied to the request and what servlet process it?

Comment: You have absolutely nothing in the logs to tell what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can **use a Java profiler to trace the request** inside the Weblogic server.

Just attach the profiler to the Weblogic server, enable instrumentation and run your request. You will see the code path it is going through.

Btw. 404 error means Not found, so you should verify that your servlet is correctly deployed on the server